# How to "override" default Magento2 "Luma" Theme with a Custom Theme

Tags: magento2, theme, overrides

I created a custom Theme with "Luma" as its parent.

Now I want to override **.less / css** stylings. (for example "header" background color)
Thats the Folder structure I have:
[image: Folder Structure]

I did copy **`"_module.less" from "vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Theme/web/css/source" to "Magento_Theme/web/css/source/"`** in my custom theme folder and changed the **"_module.less"** file but It didnt override styles, so it didnt apply on my webshop.

***I deleted the theme files in "/pub/static" and flushed magento cache, with no results.***

Does anyone know how to override ".**less**" / css stylings of the default / luma theme? I want to customize the luma theme, thats why I created my custom theme and now Id like to change some css styles.

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To override parent styles, you should create the following:

1. In your theme directory, create a `web/css/source` sub-directory.
2. Create a `_theme.less` file there.
3. Copy all variables you need from the parent `<Magento_Luma_theme_dir>/web/css/source/_theme.less`, including those which will not be changed.
4. Make the necessary changes.

More info under: [Magento Developer Docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_approach.html)

Comment: I did that now, but I cant see "variables" for "@primary__color" for example. So How could I change header background-color in "_theme.less" from the Luma Theme?

Comment: The colors are in `web/css/source/lib/variables/_colors.less`. But you can define your own color as well in your theme folder: `<Your_theme_dir>/web/css/source/_variables.less`.

Comment: Cant find that Path. Looks like it doesnt exist.. So, if i would have that file "_colors.less", could I copy the stuff and paste into "_theme.less" to override colors?

Comment: And you can define colors like that: `@color-red9: #ff0101;`.

Comment: You do not need to. You can just define a color like above: `"@primary__color: #ff0101;` in your `_theme.less` file.

Comment: Thanks, did that now. How can I "compile?" it or whatever I need to do, to see the changes? Delete cache?

Comment: Delete all files under: `pub/static/frontend/<Your_Vendor_Dir>/<your_theme_dir>` and under 
`var/view_preprocessed/less`.

Comment: Nice! Seems to work so far. One more question: How can I find out what variables i want to change? for example I wanna change header background color, how do I know in which ".less" file it is and what the variable name it is if it even has one? Kinda confused..

Comment: Well you can check the `css` source to get an idea what the variables are. Additionally you can have a look on all of the variables under `/lib/web/css/source/lib` as well.