# Is it possible to import all style from base theme into custom theme in magento 2 and how?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, luma-theme, parent-child-theme

I have newly started working on magento 2 .

I have created custom theme by keep luma theme as parent. I want to import all css of parent theme in custom theme of magento 2.

Comment: Try this i think it will help you http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136683/how-to-override-default-magento2-luma-theme-with-a-custom-theme

Comment: No need to copy the parent theme in custom theme for all styles loaded in the current theme, and you can bring current theme styling files, which you can overwrite them if needed